# Parent context.Context vs gin.Contect.Request.Context vs gin.Context

Tags: go

At my company we have a pattern of passing in parent context into our http handlers. Currently we are passing in parentContext into methods in the handler that need them `db.Query(parentCtx...)`.
My question is should we be using the gin Context or the gin Request context here instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to terminate processing if the connection is closed, use the `Request.Context`. Based on the documentation for `Done`:

> Done always returns nil (chan which will wait forever), if you want to abort your work when the connection was closed you should use Request.Context().Done() instead.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding some steps here so bear with me.
What if I don't want to abort work but just want the sql query for example to stop executing if server gracefully shuts down?
We currently have a parent context that is bound to os kill signal and that context is used for server.Shutdown.  
Edit: Thanks for helping out a fellow Turk.

Comment: One thing you can try is to use the `BaseContext` func of the `Server`, and cancel that base context once you receive shutdown. That should cancel all derived contexts, which will be in `Request.Context`

Comment: The current version of the docs says "Done returns nil (chan which will wait forever) when c.Request has no Context." which makes even less sense.